# How to fix "RCTStatusBarManager module requires that the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key in the Info.plist is set to NO"

Tags: ios, react-native

In my app I use React Native (legacy code) and iOS native components.

Recently I implemented `preferredStatusBarStyle` override in my iOS ViewController.

But `preferredStatusBarStyle` doesn't work without `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES` in Info.plist. So I changed this key to YES.

Now I have a React Native error: **"RCTStatusBarManager module requires that the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key in the Info.plist is set to NO"**.

[Error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45qLV.png)

Is there any way how to remove error without changing .plist back? I searched all legacy react code and **didn't find any use of `StatusBar` React Component**.

Answer (score 4):

I can't solve this problem by using modern `preferredStatusBarStyle` because of React Native error. But this old deprecated way to set status bar style helped: `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle()`.

I wrote this helper to change statusBar style in my app:

```
public static func updateStatusBarStyle(isLightBackground: Bool) {
  var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle
  if isLightBackground, #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    statusBarStyle = .darkContent
  } else {
    statusBarStyle = isLightBackground ? .default : .lightContent
  }
  UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(statusBarStyle, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue when setting up statusbar color and style with react-navigation/native-stack. Where to put above code or any workaround besides not using react navigation's way of setting up statusbar color, style.